# What programs export .mesh?

Tags: export, mesh, roblox

I need to export some USGS (U.S. Geological Survey) DEM (Digital Elevation Model) data into .mesh format. I need it to be in the [Roblox's .mesh format](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Mesh_file_format) though. The only program that I know that does this is [Anim8tor's program](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Anim8tor_exporter_script). Basically it makes the .mesh look like this:

```
version 1.00
36
[12.3732, 5.75607, 0.797889][0.30353, 0.52573, 0.79465][0.30902, 0.80902, 0][13.5279, 5.75607, 0.356833][0.30353, 0.52573, 0.79465][0.92705, 0.80902, 0][12.8664, 6.13804, 0.356833][0.30353, 0.52573, 0.79465][0.57295, 1.00000, 0][12.3732, 5.75607, 0.797889][0.30353, 0.52573, 0.79465][0.30902, 0.80902, 0][13.4437, 5.13804, 0.797889][0.30353, 0.52573, 0.79465][0.88197, 0.50000, 0][13.5279, 5.75607, 0.356833][0.30353, 0.52573, 0.79465][0.92705, 0.80902, 0][12.3732, 5.75607, 0.797889][0.30353, 0.52573, 0.79465][0.30902, 0.80902, 0][12.7301, 5.13804, 1.07048][0.30353, 0.52573, 0.79465][0.50000, 0.50000, 0][13.4437, 5.13804, 0.797889][0.30353, 0.52573, 0.79465][0.88197, 0.50000, 0][12.3732, 4.52, 0.797889][-0.60706, 0.00000, 0.79465][0.30902, 0.19098, 0][11.7959, 5.52, 0.356833][-0.60706, 0.00000, 0.79465][-0.00000, 0.69098, 0][11.7959, 4.75607, 0.356833][-0.60706, 0.00000, 0.79465][-0.00000, 0.30902, 0][12.3732, 4.52, 0.797889][-0.60706, 0.00000, 0.79465][0.30902, 0.19098, 0][12.3732, 5.75607, 0.797889][-0.60706, 0.00000, 0.79465][0.30902, 0.80902, 0][11.7959, 5.52, 0.356833][-0.60706, 0.00000, 0.79465][-0.00000, 0.69098, 0][12.3732, 4.52, 0.797889][-0.60706, 0.00000, 0.79465][0.30902, 0.19098, 0][12.7301, 5.13804, 1.07048][-0.60706, 0.00000, 0.79465][0.50000, 0.50000, 0][12.3732, 5.75607, 0.797889][-0.60706, 0.00000, 0.79465][0.30902, 0.80902, 0][13.4437, 5.13804, 0.797889][0.30353, -0.52573, 0.79465][0.88197, 0.50000, 0][12.8664, 4.13804, 0.356833][0.30353, -0.52573, 0.79465][0.57295, 0.00000, 0][13.5279, 4.52, 0.356833][0.30353, -0.52573, 0.79465][0.92705, 0.19098, 0][13.4437, 5.13804, 0.797889][0.30353, -0.52573, 0.79465][0.88197, 0.50000, 0][12.3732, 4.52, 0.797889][0.30353, -0.52573, 0.79465][0.30902, 0.19098, 0][12.8664, 4.13804, 0.356833][0.30353, -0.52573, 0.79465][0.57295, 0.00000, 0][13.4437, 5.13804, 0.797889][0.30353, -0.52573, 0.79465][0.88197, 0.50000, 0][12.7301, 5.13804, 1.07048][0.30353, -0.52573, 0.79465][0.50000, 0.50000, 0][12.3732, 4.52, 0.797889][0.30353, -0.52573, 0.79465][0.30902, 0.19098, 0][13.5279, 5.75607, 0.356833][0.98225, -0.00000, 0.18759][0.92705, 0.80902, 0][13.6642, 4.75607, -0.356811][0.98225, -0.00000, 0.18759][1.00000, 0.30902, 0][13.6642, 5.52, -0.356811][0.98225, -0.00000, 0.18759][1.00000, 0.69098, 0][13.5279, 5.75607, 0.356833][0.98225, -0.00000, 0.18759][0.92705, 0.80902, 0][13.5279, 4.52, 0.356833][0.98225, -0.00000, 0.18759][0.92705, 0.19098, 0][13.6642, 4.75607, -0.356811][0.98225, -0.00000, 0.18759][1.00000, 0.30902, 0][13.5279, 5.75607, 0.356833][0.98225, -0.00000, 0.18759][0.92705, 0.80902, 0][13.4437, 5.13804, 0.797889][0.98225, -0.00000, 0.18759][0.88197, 0.50000, 0][13.5279, 4.52, 0.356833][0.98225, -0.00000, 0.18759][0.92705, 0.19098, 0][11.7959, 5.52, 0.356833][-0.49112, 0.85065, 0.18759][-0.00000, 0.69098, 0][12.5938, 6.13804, -0.356811][-0.49112, 0.85065, 0.18759][0.42705, 1.00000, 0][11.9322, 5.75607, -0.356811][-0.49112, 0.85065, 0.18759][0.07295, 0.80902, 0][11.7959, 5.52, 0.356833][-0.49112, 0.85065, 0.18759][-0.00000, 0.69098, 0][12.8664, 6.13804, 0.356833][-0.49112, 0.85065, 0.18759][0.57295, 1.00000, 0][12.5938, 6.13804, -0.356811][-0.49112, 0.85065, 0.18759][0.42705, 1.00000, 0][11.7959, 5.52, 0.356833][-0.49112, 0.85065, 0.18759][-0.00000, 0.69098, 0][12.3732, 5.75607, 0.797889][-0.49112, 0.85065, 0.18759][0.30902, 0.80902, 0][12.8664, 6.13804, 0.356833][-0.49112, 0.85065, 0.18759][0.57295, 1.00000, 0][12.8664, 4.13804, 0.356833][-0.49112, -0.85065, 0.18759][0.57295, 0.00000, 0][11.9322, 4.52, -0.356811][-0.49112, -0.85065, 0.18759][0.07295, 0.19098, 0][12.5938, 4.13804, -0.356811][-0.49112, -0.85065, 0.18759][0.42705, 0.00000, 0][12.8664, 4.13804, 0.356833][-0.49112, -0.85065, 0.18759][0.57295, 0.00000, 0][11.7959, 4.75607, 0.356833][-0.49112, -0.85065, 0.18759][-0.00000, 0.30902, 0][11.9322, 4.52, -0.356811][-0.49112, -0.85065, 0.18759][0.07295, 0.19098, 0][12.8664, 4.13804, 0.356833][-0.49112, -0.85065, 0.18759][0.57295, 0.00000, 0][12.3732, 4.52, 0.797889][-0.49112, -0.85065, 0.18759][0.30902, 0.19098, 0][11.7959, 4.75607, 0.356833][-0.49112, -0.85065, 0.18759][-0.00000, 0.30902, 0][12.8664, 6.13804, 0.356833][0.49112, 0.85065, -0.18759][0.57295, 1.00000, 0][13.0869, 5.75607, -0.797867][0.49112, 0.85065, -0.18759][0.69098, 0.80902, 0][12.5938, 6.13804, -0.356811][0.49112, 0.85065, -0.18759][0.42705, 1.00000, 0][12.8664, 6.13804, 0.356833][0.49112, 0.85065, -0.18759][0.57295, 1.00000, 0][13.6642, 5.52, -0.356811][0.49112, 0.85065, -0.18759][1.00000, 0.69098, 0][13.0869, 5.75607, -0.797867][0.49112, 0.85065, -0.18759][0.69098, 0.80902, 0][12.8664, 6.13804, 0.356833][0.49112, 0.85065, -0.18759][0.57295, 1.00000, 0][13.5279, 5.75607, 0.356833][0.49112, 0.85065, -0.18759][0.92705, 0.80902, 0][13.6642, 5.52, -0.356811][0.49112, 0.85065, -0.18759][1.00000, 0.69098, 0][13.6642, 4.75607, -0.356811][0.49112, -0.85065, -0.18759][1.00000, 0.30902, 0][12.5938, 4.13804, -0.356811][0.49112, -0.85065, -0.18759][0.42705, 0.00000, 0][13.0869, 4.52, -0.797867][0.49112, -0.85065, -0.18759][0.69098, 0.19098, 0][13.6642, 4.75607, -0.356811][0.49112, -0.85065, -0.18759][1.00000, 0.30902, 0][12.8664, 4.13804, 0.356833][0.49112, -0.85065, -0.18759][0.57295, 0.00000, 0][12.5938, 4.13804, -0.356811][0.49112, -0.85065, -0.18759][0.42705, 0.00000, 0][13.6642, 4.75607, -0.356811][0.49112, -0.85065, -0.18759][1.00000, 0.30902, 0][13.5279, 4.52, 0.356833][0.49112, -0.85065, -0.18759][0.92705, 0.19098, 0][12.8664, 4.13804, 0.356833][0.49112, -0.85065, -0.18759][0.57295, 0.00000, 0][11.7959, 4.75607, 0.356833][-0.98225, 0.00000, -0.18759][-0.00000, 0.30902, 0][12.0164, 5.13804, -0.797867][-0.98225, 0.00000, -0.18759][0.11803, 0.50000, 0][11.9322, 4.52, -0.356811][-0.98225, 0.00000, -0.18759][0.07295, 0.19098, 0][11.7959, 4.75607, 0.356833][-0.98225, 0.00000, -0.18759][-0.00000, 0.30902, 0][11.9322, 5.75607, -0.356811][-0.98225, 0.00000, -0.18759][0.07295, 0.80902, 0][12.0164, 5.13804, -0.797867][-0.98225, 0.00000, -0.18759][0.11803, 0.50000, 0][11.7959, 4.75607, 0.356833][-0.98225, 0.00000, -0.18759][-0.00000, 0.30902, 0][11.7959, 5.52, 0.356833][-0.98225, 0.00000, -0.18759][-0.00000, 0.69098, 0][11.9322, 5.75607, -0.356811][-0.98225, 0.00000, -0.18759][0.07295, 0.80902, 0][13.0869, 5.75607, -0.797867][0.60707, 0.00000, -0.79465][0.69098, 0.80902, 0][13.0869, 4.52, -0.797867][0.60707, 0.00000, -0.79465][0.69098, 0.19098, 0][12.7301, 5.13804, -1.07046][0.60707, 0.00000, -0.79465][0.50000, 0.50000, 0][13.0869, 5.75607, -0.797867][0.60707, 0.00000, -0.79465][0.69098, 0.80902, 0][13.6642, 4.75607, -0.356811][0.60707, 0.00000, -0.79465][1.00000, 0.30902, 0][13.0869, 4.52, -0.797867][0.60707, 0.00000, -0.79465][0.69098, 0.19098, 0][13.0869, 5.75607, -0.797867][0.60707, 0.00000, -0.79465][0.69098, 0.80902, 0][13.6642, 5.52, -0.356811][0.60707, 0.00000, -0.79465][1.00000, 0.69098, 0][13.6642, 4.75607, -0.356811][0.60707, 0.00000, -0.79465][1.00000, 0.30902, 0][12.0164, 5.13804, -0.797867][-0.30353, 0.52574, -0.79465][0.11803, 0.50000, 0][13.0869, 5.75607, -0.797867][-0.30353, 0.52574, -0.79465][0.69098, 0.80902, 0][12.7301, 5.13804, -1.07046][-0.30353, 0.52574, -0.79465][0.50000, 0.50000, 0][12.0164, 5.13804, -0.797867][-0.30353, 0.52574, -0.79465][0.11803, 0.50000, 0][12.5938, 6.13804, -0.356811][-0.30353, 0.52574, -0.79465][0.42705, 1.00000, 0][13.0869, 5.75607, -0.797867][-0.30353, 0.52574, -0.79465][0.69098, 0.80902, 0][12.0164, 5.13804, -0.797867][-0.30353, 0.52574, -0.79465][0.11803, 0.50000, 0][11.9322, 5.75607, -0.356811][-0.30353, 0.52574, -0.79465][0.07295, 0.80902, 0][12.5938, 6.13804, -0.356811][-0.30353, 0.52574, -0.79465][0.42705, 1.00000, 0][13.0869, 4.52, -0.797867][-0.30353, -0.52574, -0.79465][0.69098, 0.19098, 0][12.0164, 5.13804, -0.797867][-0.30353, -0.52574, -0.79465][0.11803, 0.50000, 0][12.7301, 5.13804, -1.07046][-0.30353, -0.52574, -0.79465][0.50000, 0.50000, 0][13.0869, 4.52, -0.797867][-0.30353, -0.52574, -0.79465][0.69098, 0.19098, 0][11.9322, 4.52, -0.356811][-0.30353, -0.52574, -0.79465][0.07295, 0.19098, 0][12.0164, 5.13804, -0.797867][-0.30353, -0.52574, -0.79465][0.11803, 0.50000, 0][13.0869, 4.52, -0.797867][-0.30353, -0.52574, -0.79465][0.69098, 0.19098, 0][12.5938, 4.13804, -0.356811][-0.30353, -0.52574, -0.79465][0.42705, 0.00000, 0][11.9322, 4.52, -0.356811][-0.30353, -0.52574, -0.79465][0.07295, 0.19098, 0]
```

That mesh looks something like [this](http://learnsolidworks.com/wp-content/uploads/1_solidworks_dodecahedron_tutorial.png)

The problem is that I have about 200MB of .3ds data that I need to convert to Roblox's .mesh but Anim8or's .mesh exporter crashes.

Is there any program that exports .mesh like that?

PS: I know Roblox disabled .mesh uploading but I have a script that converts it into regular Roblox terrain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the model in [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) and [export it to Roblox's .mesh](http://www.roblox.com/BlenderExport-py-item?id=25895023)

==Edit==

Sorry, I just pointed at some stuff that i thought would work, but when I tried it I noticed that the add-on was flawed (not much of it was working) so I edited it a bit (it is the first blender add-on I have made, and I am not too sure about the .mesh part, but it might work, however expect bugs):

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Export Roblox Mesh (.mesh)",
    "description": "Exports the selected model to .mesh    Source: http://www.roblox.com/BlenderExport-py-item?id=25895023",
    "author": "Original by stravant, then edited",
    "version": (1,0),
    "location": "File > Export",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "http://www.roblox.com/BlenderExport-py-item?id=25895023",
    "category": "Import-Export"
}

import bpy

def get_face_vertex_array(face, uvface, mesh, matrix):
    varray = []
    for inx, verti in enumerate(face.vertices):
        tcoord = (matrix * mesh.vertices[verti].co).to_tuple(3)
        tnorm = (matrix.to_3x3() * face.normal).normalized().to_tuple(3)
        tuv = (0,0,0)
        varray.append((tcoord, tnorm, tuv))
    return varray

def write_tuple_3(tuple, file, flip):
    if flip:
        file.write("["+str(tuple[0])+","+str(tuple[2])+","+str(tuple[1])+"]")
    else:
        file.write("["+str(tuple[0])+","+str(tuple[1])+","+str(tuple[2])+"]")

def write_verts(varray, nverts, file):
    file.write(str(nverts) + "\n")
    for vert in varray:
        write_tuple_3(vert[0], file, True)
        write_tuple_3(vert[1], file, True)
        write_tuple_3(vert[2], file, False)
    file.write("\n")

def do_export(path,selected_only):
    file = open(path, "w")
    file.write("version 1.00\n")
    tmp_mesh_verts = []
    tmp_mesh_size = 0
    invert_rot = False
    scene = bpy.context.scene

    for obj in (selected_only and bpy.context.selected_objects or bpy.data.objects):
        if obj.type == "MESH":
            tmp_mesh = obj.to_mesh(scene,True, "PREVIEW")
            matrix = obj.matrix_world.copy()
            for index, face in enumerate(tmp_mesh.tessfaces):
                verts = get_face_vertex_array(face, None, tmp_mesh, matrix)
                if len(verts) > 3:
                    if invert_rot:
                        tmp_mesh_verts.extend([verts[2], verts[1], verts[0], verts[3], verts[2], verts[0]])
                    else:
                        tmp_mesh_verts.extend([verts[0], verts[1], verts[2], verts[0], verts[2], verts[3]])
                    tmp_mesh_size += 2
                else:
                    if invert_rot:
                        tmp_mesh_verts.extend([verts[2], verts[1], verts[0]])
                    else:
                        tmp_mesh_verts.extend([verts[0], verts[1], verts[2]])
                    tmp_mesh_size += 1
            bpy.data.meshes.remove(tmp_mesh)
    write_verts(tmp_mesh_verts, tmp_mesh_size, file)
    file.close()

class RbxExporter(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Export model to .mesh"""
    bl_idname = "export.mesh"
    bl_label = "Export RBXMesh"

    filepath = bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype="FILE_PATH")
    ending = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="File ending", description="The file ending to be used", maxlen= 1024, default= ".mesh")
    selected_only = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Selected objects only", description="Export only the selected objects?", default= False)

    def execute(self, context):
        print("RBX::Execute")
        do_export(self.filepath + (self.filepath.endswith(self.ending) and "" or self.ending),self.selected_only)
        return {"FINISHED"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("RBX::Invoke")
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

def menu_func(self, context):
    print("RBX::MenuFunc")
    self.layout.operator(RbxExporter.bl_idname, text="Roblox Mesh (.mesh)")

def register():
    print("RBX::Register")
    bpy.utils.register_class(RbxExporter)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    print("RBX::Unregister")
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RbxExporter)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I tried it on the monkey head, and it seems to work.
Also to note is that i removed the UV mapping and changed lots of stuff (no idea if it is handled correctly in memory and so).

Remember to activate it.
The option to export to .mesh should appear in the export section of the file menu.

---

Another method you could use is to import it in Blender, export it as .obj, and [import it in roblox](http://www.roblox.com/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=115382746).

Comment: How do I use it? I tried installing it as an addon but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @GShocked I did not try it, now when i did i noticed that it was quite flawed. Edited the answer, hope that it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I am using this in [this](http://www.roblox.com/Polygon-to-terrain-voxel-converter-item?id=97274434) poly to terrain converter script. It also created about a 40% decrease in output file size compared to Anim8or's.