# Separating a list of sublists into different lines

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have this table:

```
{{-4.82378, 0.729424, -7.18091},{-0.21796, 0.95900, 0.18116},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0},{-4.81365, 0.730056, -7.17529},{-0.16721, 0.94651, 0.27596},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0},{-4.80815, 0.739832, -7.19562},{-0.33649, 0.84809, 0.40930},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0},{-10.911, 0.727, -5.829},{0.89435, 0.44736, 0.00000},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0},{-10.91, 0.725, -5.823},{0.89435, 0.44736, 0.00000},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0},{-10.911, 0.727, -5.83},{0.89435, 0.44736, 0.00000},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0},{-3.08688, 0.55511, -5.20297},{-0.47515, 0.77221, 0.42182},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0},{-3.07362, 0.572835, -5.20486},{-0.73111, 0.66049, 0.17094},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0},{-3.07302, 0.576144, -5.22018},{-0.59853, 0.77112, 0.21710},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0},{-4.97087, 0.851932, -5.12065},{-0.45030, 0.63469, -0.62801}, etc... for 115MB}
```

It is all in one straight line, no `\n` here. If you notice, each list of 3 floats is separated by a comma and everything is withheld in one large list. Lua is returning me `constant table overflow` so I think separating this into lines would help.

How would I go about separating `{{0,0,0},{1,1,1},{2,2,2}}` into something like:

```
{
{0,0,0}{1,1,1}{2,2,2}
}
```

so that I could put anything between those two main curly braces and have my Rbx.Lua script run without returning `constant table overflow`.

Comment: Which version of Lua are you using?

Comment: I don't believe newlines will help here. I think you probably need to build the table up dynamically.

Comment: According to their website Roblox uses Lua 5.1.

Comment: @EtanReisner So I have to build the table in parts?

Comment: Is this table in a file or something?

Comment: @YuHao The table is Roblox .mesh data that is formatted to look like that. It shows Mount Everest and surrounding area taken from USGS DEM data. It is in a text file but I pasted it into a Roblox model because if I try to paste it into a script in Roblox, Roblox crashes. So I have to put it into a Roblox model and import the model.

Comment: Yes, I believe you've hit the maximum constant limit that lua can handle in a chunk (I believe it is per-chunk but I'd have to go check to be sure). So you'll need to build it up by hand beyond that point. (You can use multiple literal tables that you loop and concat in different chunks or files whatever.)

Comment: This constant limit is not a Lua but rather a LuaJIT / Lua interpreter specific limitation.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is too big, it does not matter if you add some line breaks here and there, in the end it is the same table that is handled by Lua.

To solve your problem, you could try to either parse sections of the data and add together the result. Because Lua can't handle huge tables.

Or parse the data as a string and parse it part by part. To my knowledge strings do not have any limit per se.

Everything to avoid huge tables of data being stored at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, however with that script you provided me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956989/what-programs-export-mesh/30990113), I am not getting the same error.